# Passing variables with include statement in Jinja2 template

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I have a html file containing the following snippet of code in Jinja2 templating language.

```
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    {% with textarea="txtMessageContent" %}
        {% include "vvv/vvv/TinyMCE.html" %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am trying to pass the variable textarea to the TinyMCE.html template which contains the following code.

```
{% block InitTinyMCE %}
<script src="https://x.x.x/x/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
alert(textarea);
    $(document).ready(function (textarea){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: textarea,
            menubar: true,
            plugins: "hr code preview",
            content_css:"https://x.x.x/x/css/backend-boostrap.css",
            remove_linebreaks: false,
            convert_newlines_to_brs: true
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I load the page I see that the variable is not being passed throught. I can confirm this due to the following error.

textarea is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put double-curly braces around variables in Jinja

```
{% block InitTinyMCE %}
<script src="https://x.x.x/x/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "{{ textarea }}",
            menubar: true,
            plugins: "hr code preview",
            content_css:"https://x.x.x/x/css/backend-boostrap.css",
            remove_linebreaks: false,
            convert_newlines_to_brs: true
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```